# Firebug is returning: document.getElementById(...) is null -what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a unit conversion calculator for a three-ingredient recipe, but can't get the calculations to run through after hitting 'get ingredients' button. Firebug is returning the getElementById lines as null? JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs();
});

window.onload = init;

function init(){

document.getElementById("calc").onclick=function(){

    var pbc=Number(document.getElementById("pbc").value);   

    var dc=Number(document.getElementById("dc").value)* .0333333333;    
    var pb=Number(document.getElementById("pb").value)* .0166666667;    
    var sea=Number(document.getElementById("sea").value)* .0020833333;
    var dcTotal= ("dc" * "pbc");
    var pbTotal= ("pb" * "pbc");
    var seaTotal= ("sea" * "pbc");
    document.getElementById("resultdc").innerHTML=dcTotal.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("resultpb").innerHTML=pbTotal.toFixed(1);
    document.getElementById("resultsea").innerHTML=seaTotal.toFixed(1);
    }
}
```

portion of HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)">
  <label for="pbc">How many Dark Chocolate Peanut Butter Cups would you like `to make?</label>`
  <input type="text" name="pbc" id="pbc">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button"id="calc" value="Get Ingredients">
  </form>

  <p id="resultdc"> Cup(s) of Dark Chocolate Chips</p>

  <p id="resultpb"> Cup(s) of Peanut Butter</p>  

  <p id="resultsea"> Teaspoon(s) of Sea Salt</p>
```

Comment: The HTML seems to be missing quite a few of the elements referenced in the javascript, like `#dc`, `#pb`, `#sea` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by putting quotes around your variables, you ar econverting them into strings and therefore not able to be used for calculations:

eg

```
var dcTotal= ("dc" * "pbc");
var pbTotal= ("pb" * "pbc");
var seaTotal= ("sea" * "pbc");
```

should be

```
var dcTotal= (dc * pbc);
var pbTotal= (pb * pbc);
var seaTotal= (sea * pbc);
```

also note that the following line

```
document.getElementById("resultdc").innerHTML=dcTotal.toFixed(1);
```

will replace all content in the ("resultdc") div, with the value (dcTotal.toFixed(1))

you should change your html to something like..

```
<p><span id="resultdc"></span> Cup(s) of Dark Chocolate Chips</p>
```

which will fill in the desired number into the span and not replace the text content.

Comment: Thank you, fixed this as well.
Firebug is still reporting an error with:
var dc=Number(document.getElementById("dc").value)* .0333333333; 
as null.

Comment: like @adeneo said - there does not seem to be an input with the id of "dc","pb" or "sea"  listed in your html

Comment: I see what you mean...is the program looking for these variables as separate user inputs like the number of peanut butter cups I'm asking for? -If so, what I needed the program to do was take the pbc input from the user, and use that information to calculate how much chocolate, peanut butter, and salt the recipe calls for...and return that information upon hitting the 'get ingredients' (or 'calc') button.

Comment: yes you will either need inputs to take the values from or do it programmatically in the js (and remove the requirements of getting the input values). it should then be a simple matter of taking the values, doing the calculations and then displaying the results.

Comment: Solved it! Got everything to work. Thanks so much for the help everyone! (: @gavgrif

Comment: you're welcome., I hope you continue learning and enjoying coding. Good luck with everything. :)

Answer (score 0):

need a space between `"button"` and `id`

```
<input type="button" id="calc" value="Get Ingredients">
```

Comment: Thank you for finding that, fixed it...but the 'null' value is still being returned. :(